# Error in Pure Componenet State in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-form

I am facing a bizarre error. PFB:

I am actually using a **PureComponent** Class and on **componentWillReceiveProps** method, I am updating the current state with the nextPropValues. Data is all coming perfectly but I am getting **undefined** error when I assign the values thru **setState** method. Hence I tried Console.log it, the data objects are received properly but when I try to access the attributes inside the object I am getting **Undefined**. Can you make me understand where I had made a mistake?

Thanks!

[image]

**Console:**
[image]

**Debugging Mode:**
[image]

***As you can see below when I access the attributes inside the book object, I am getting undefined.***

[image]

**Console:**
[image]

**Debugging Mode:**
[image]

Comment: can you make a demo kind of thing on codesandbox.io?

Comment: Hard to tell further, but what you describe can only happen if you were to receive an empty object, which would later be populated with values, and therefore display correctly in console, by the time it gets there. I would play around with alernative lifecycle hooks, to see when is it actually populated

Comment: Look at your second picture again, it logs `undefined` before it logs the book.

Comment: I am using componenetWillMount() to fetch the data from the API and once it's a success I am updating the Redux, hence I use the componentWillReceiveProps() to update the PureComponent's state.

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thank you so much for all of your replies.

I have fixed it by adding a if(book._id) {this.setState(...)}... But not sure on which hook it is getting undefined. If anyone could explain? Thanks, Guys

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all of your replies.

As in the below code: I have fixed it by adding a *if(book) {this.setState(...)}*...

But not sure on which hook it is getting undefined.

**Explanation:**
*This is because, Initially as the component renders this book object will be empty, as I am accessing the attributes inside book object, it throws an undefined error. So I gave an If condition, hence it skips the setState method where I am accessing the book object's attribute. Hope I was clear.*

Thanks, Guys

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// debugger;
let book = nextProps.books.book;
// console.log(book);
if (book) {
  // console.log(book._id);
  this.setState({
    formdata: {
      _id: book._id,
      name: book.name,
      author: book.author,
      review: book.review,
      pages: book.pages,
      rating: book.rating,
      price: book.price,
    },
  });
}
```

}